# expo-image-picker showing pdf for selection on android and after selecting the PDF app crashed

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-image-picker

I am using 'expo-image-picker' to select Images and videos in my project.
When we are passing **mediaTypes=ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All** for android it is also showing the PDF files and on selection of that PDF app is getting crashed.

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'

export default function App() {

  const openGallery=async()=>{
    console.log("openGallery")
    try {
      const result=await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes:ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        exif:false,
        quality: 1,
        base64:false
      })
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
 
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>openGallery()}>
      <Text>Select image</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

PDF should not visible in filesystem of android as we need only Image and Videos.

Comment: Create an issue on the GitHub. It's a library issue.

Comment: Yes I created they Fixed. Thanks @VasylNahuliak

Comment: @DeepakPaleewal this issue is still exists, can you please confirm if it is working fine at your end ?

Comment: this issue is fixed @GiteshPurbia